# disable close button in a dialog opened from backingbean (primefaces)

Tags: primefaces, requestcontext, opendialog

there is a bug when opening dialog from ManagedBean with:

`requestcontext.getcurrentInstance().opendialog("mydialog",map,null).`

I set closable to false in the map as:

```
map.put(“closable”, false);
```

but the button close[X] appears in dialog. 
I also tested:

```
map.put(“closable”, “false”);
map.put(“toolbar”, false);
map.put(“showCloseIcon”, false);
```

…. but the button doesn't dispare
any help thx
(sorry for my english)

Comment: Maybe I get you wrong but this is definetly not the way how to open a dialog in PrimeFaces. Can you describe what you want to achieve? And please provide some html, too.

Comment: i want to open details.xhtml in a dialog from a bean and execute actions when users click to open it 
 and also when they leave it. so i have to disable the close icon to forbid users to close the dialog with the close[X] button but with a
 button 'Cancel'from details.xhtml. i tested this: 

 Map map = HashMap();
 map.put("closable", false);

 RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().openDialog("/pathTo/details.xhtml",map, null);

but the dialog still has the close icon clickable.
thx for answers and sorry for my english.

Comment: isn't there any answer ??